# Is there a reason to not define keys, foreign or others

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm taking over some code which relies on collection of Oracle tables which have no apparent keys (primary, candidate or foreign) defined to Oracle explicitly but are used as keys nonetheless. Is there a valid reason to not define them, even if they are disabled?

The tables are defined, and there's SQL to do something like select * from table1 inner join table2 on table1.somekey. The fields exist and the query runs (slowly), but there are no constraints defined. Sometimes the columns are defined as not null and unique, but that's the closest thing to a key they have. At no place does SQL define any foreign key constraints.  I could define them myself and it would work, but I wonder if there are any reasons to not define them, even if they are turned off.  Right now, the only way of determining a relationship is to find select queries somewhere in the code base and seeing what joins are actually done.

My goal in this question is to find out if there is some "cost" to defining a constraint even if they are turned off.  This particular set of tables is not used for high volume, but more for user and feature access.  Please tell me if I'm insane for wanting these defined.

Thank you from the Woodsman.

Comment: I think real-life constraints are more likely than technical one. (budget, time, knowledge.)
There is a slight performance cost of these extra database objects in some cases, but it is mostly marginal especially for non high volume tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, there's little reason not to define the constraints.

Constraints help keeping your data with a good level of quality. If you don't add them or if you disable them, then no checks are performed by the database when data is modified. You'll be flying blind and would need to trust *all* applications that use the database are doing it well. Not a good idea in general. Applications are full of bugs all the time.

Also, applications' importance fades in time; applications become obsolete. The data they managed survives much longer. It's still useful and valuable (I'm talking real $ here) easily 10 years (and more) after the applications were decomissioned. Data should be kept safe.

> My goal in this question is to find out if there is some "cost" to defining a constraint

Yes, there's some cost, but is usually minimal. Constraints may require an extra index and/or may require some extra processing in the database side (not your app). This is, again, minimal and you would rarely notice it unless you are processing millions of transactions in short periods of time and need to squeeze up to the last millisecond of performance. But this is usually not the case.

So, in short, 99.99% of the time you should have constraints in place, protecting your data.

Comment: @Woodsman: constraints have another benefit: they _document_ your database and show how the tables relate to each other. e.g. you immediately see which columns should be used for joining tables because of foreign keys

Answer (score 1):

There are good reasons to avoid foreign key constraints in certain *data warehouse* environments.  But I completely agree with The Impaler's answer that it almost never makes sense to ignore constraints in an *online transaction processing* (OLTP) environment.

Constraints still make sense in most data warehouse environments that use an extract, transform, and load (ETL) process.  Data is extracted from a source like a text file, transformed by an external program like Informatica, and then loaded into the database where it should already conform with the data integrity rules.

But for an extract, load, and transform (ELT) process, it makes sense to have tables without any constraints.  Data is extracted from a source like a text file, loaded into staging tables, and then transformed by the database into the final tables.  Those staging tables may be filled with dirty data, so they typically won't have any constraints or even the right data types.  The idea behind ELT is that a good database like Oracle is much better at analyzing, cleaning, and transforming data than other applications.  And removing constraints can boost performance in several ways.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree. My answer focused on OLTPs only. For other non-OLTP applications constraints can be a burden. It's also the case in admin tasks: for example, when restoring data foreign keys may be disabled for some time, while data is temporarily inconsistent. +1